# Is there a way to compile a SwiftUI App for Android

Tags: android, swiftui

I have a written an App for iOS in SwiftUI. But I need an App for Android too. My question is: Is there any way to compile my SwiftUI App for Android? And if not, what is the best next step for developing an Android App, is there any programming language for Android, wich is similar to SwiftUI?

Thanks for your time.
Boothosh

Comment: Nope, SwiftUI is Apple only. There have been a [couple](https://github.com/SwiftWebUI/SwiftWebUI) [attempts](https://github.com/TokamakUI/Tokamak) to bring it to other platforms, but it's all still very experimental.

Comment: Okay :( Which language would you say is the best, or which is the closest to the SwiftUI?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I've only worked with Apple platforms. I'm just as interested as you in an alternative

Comment: :) Problem is I have no Idea how to develop a similar App for android, because I struggled with my SwiftUI App, and I developed with SwiftUI before...

Comment: Jetpack Compose with Kotlin is probably the closest in terms of a native solution. React Native and Flutter may be worth looking at if you have any Javascript or Dart experience respectively. All are reactive declarative frameworks like SwiftUI.

Comment: Use Flutter! Time of native apps is over.

Comment: @TimoBähr lol... same thing was said by Cordova, PhoneGap, Xamarin, React Native etc... AirBnB decided to abandon RN in 2018: https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/sunsetting-react-native-1868ba28e30a so NO, I do not think that "Flutter is ThE WiNneR aNd WiLl mAkE NaTivE aPPs ObsOLEte.". I've heard that crap for 11 years now. Never ever turned out to be true.

Comment: @Sajjon Let's see, I'm working full-time only on Flutter apps since two years now. I don't see any of these problems I had with Xamarin, React Native or Ionic. Only problem of Flutter was bad bugs for iOS in past, but they are fixed now.